# Is there such an idiom as "en être de même"?

Tags: grammaire, sens, expressions-idiomatiques

> **Il en est de même** de la découverte du Nouveau-Monde.

Does this mean "It's been the same since the discovery of the New World?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*En être de même* means that something (referred to by the *en*) also applies to something else.

Your sentence thus could be translated into English as

> The same applies to the discovery of the New World.

Comment: Merci pour toutes vos explications. Je crois que j'ai besoin d'un dictionnaire meilleur :)